# make an expandable table view cell through first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows, where a user can click on any width of the row, and it gets expanded to give extra information. Here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/0xd06kwo/2/)

html table code

```
<table id="report" border="1" style="width:100%" >
    <tr>
        <th> First </th>
        <th> Second </th>
        <th> Third </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>1st title</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            dummy text 1<br>
            dummy text 1<br>
            dummy text 1<br>
        </td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
         <td>2nd title</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>2</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            dummy text 2 <br>
            dummy text 2<br>
            dummy text 2<br>
        </td>
    </tr>           

</table>
```

script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#report tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#report tbody tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#report tbody tr:first-child").show();

    $("#report tbody tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

I am trying to modify this table a bit, i want that when a user clicks on any value in first column(in this case user clicks on 1st title or 2nd title)  then only the view for that row should expand. Currently the view gets expanded on any position of the row. can anyone please tell me how to do so

Comment: You mean, only the first column should be clickable?

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL yes for expandable view only first column should be clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be only the first column to be clickable, attach event to the first `td` of each row:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tbody tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tbody tr:first-child").show();

        $("#report tbody tr.odd td:first-child").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().next("tr").toggle();
            $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" border="1" style="width:100%" >
    <tr>
        <th> First </th>
        <th> Second </th>
        <th> Third </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>1st title</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            dummy text 1<br>
            dummy text 1<br>
            dummy text 1<br>
        </td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
         <td>2nd title</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>2</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            dummy text 2 <br>
            dummy text 2<br>
            dummy text 2<br>
        </td>
    </tr>           

</table>
```

Comment: This wont work. `$(this).next("tr")` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#report tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
  $("#report tbody tr:not(.odd)").hide();
  $("#report tbody tr:first-child").show();

  $("#report tbody tr.odd").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:first').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").toggle();
      $(this).closest('tr').find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
  });
  //$("#report").jExpand();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Second</th>
    <th>Third</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st title</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10">dummy text 1
      <br>dummy text 1
      <br>dummy text 1
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2nd title</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10">dummy text 2
      <br>dummy text 2
      <br>dummy text 2
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your code snippet if i am clicking values under second and third column then also the view is expanding but i want that the view should expand on the click of items under first column only